# How can i connect to server through ssh tunnel in python

Tags: python, sockets, ssh

i have a python chat client using socket, i would like to connect to the chat server through an ssh server, i saw paramiko

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('<hostname>', username='<username>', password='<password>', key_filename='<path/to/openssh-private-key-file>')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

but i cannt figure out how link this with my socket connection like this

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor
import sys

class EchoClient(LineReceiver):
    end="Bye-bye!"
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Hello, world!")
        self.sendLine("What a fine day it is.")
        self.sendLine(self.end)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "receive:", line
        if line==self.end:
            self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection failed:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection lost:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    factory = EchoClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 8000, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so How can i connect to server through ssh tunnel in python ?

Comment: Create the ssh tunnel on the cmdline then portforward and connect to the local side listening port

Comment: cann't it forward it through python itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [Twisted Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch) and they have [examples](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/index.html) of implementing simple SSH client/server that might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use invoke_shell() method on SSHClient, it returns socket-like object (channel), so you can create new ssh tunnel the same way you do it in the shell. And all following connections can be accessed through this channel.